# Netbeans build with dependencies building my integration-tests twice

Tags: maven, integration-testing, netbeans-7, maven-failsafe-plugin

I've got a parent module which has the following child modules

```xml
<modules>
    <module>entities</module>
    <module>util</module>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>reports</module>
    <module>user-interface</module>
    <module>integration-tests</module>
</modules>
```

I'm using fail-safe plugin to run the integration tests. Is there a way I can tell maven to compile it's dependencies which are entities,utils and ejb before running the integration-tests in Netbeans ?

It's easy to do the above in command line. I can just go to parent pom.xml and use the following

> mvn --projects util,entities,ejb,integration-tests install

But in Netbeans when I select the integration-tests project and check the "Build with dependencies" for an action and then right click integration-tests project and select Build, Netbeans builds all the child projects and then builds "integration-tests".

> Problem is: netbeans seems to be adding integration-tests to the child project list aswell which is making integration-tests build twice and my tests are running twice.

```
Scanning for projects...
Reactor Build Order:

Utilities
Entities
Reports
EJB 
Integration Tests


[failsafe:integration-test]
builds Integration Tests

.... finishes building above modules

[failsafe:integration-test]
and then it build Integration Tests again
```

---

Comment: "and then builds itself" - what is "itself" referring to?

Comment: sorry. I've updated the question. By itself I meant the "integration-test" project. When i right click on "intergration-test" project and select build, "integration-test" is listed in the "reactor build order/child modules" so after building the child modules including integration-tests it builds integration-tests again

Comment: Define the dependencies to the other project in the integration-test module which automactially orders the building into the correct one.